# Why would you use promises over async when writing JS unit tests in truffle?

Tags: truffle, testing, mocha

I'm getting started with writing JS unit tests in the Truffle framework.  I'm curious to learn when to use promises over async?  On the surface, async seems a lot cleaner and easier to use for testing purposes.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar to work with Promises.

Comment: It is a personal/technical preference. If you already have lots of code using promises switching to async/await might not be worth of the effort. .

Comment: Also, await/async are not available is some environement such as google functions. So you have to use promise. As @Ismael said, it demends on you and on your environment